# Could not load configuration file krb5.conf (No such file or directory)

Tags: jboss, kerberos, jboss-eap-6

I am using jboss eap 6.1 for one of my web application and using krb5.xml for single signon. I placed the **krb5.conf** in JBOSS_HOME/bin path and also /etc path.

When I start jboss server using ./standalone.sh it is working fine. But I added jboss as service in linux.But while starting jboss using **service jboss-as-standalone.sh start**, it is throwing below error:

**javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not load configuration file krb5.conf (No such file or directory)**.

Could you please help me why it is throwing this error and where I need to place this krb5.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the path to absolute path and it worked fine. I don't know why it is not working with default path.

in web.xml it was like:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
    <param-value>krb5.conf</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and I copied the krb5.conf file to /etc path and then changed the param value to:

```
<param-value>/etc/krb5.conf</param-value>
```